# Dynamically generated input textfield value setting issue in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have dynamically generated textfield in Reactjs. The input textfield treated as separate component. When i try to set value in dynamically generated textfield, I get only last input value. All other input values are over write. We can use SWITCH case but if we add more input field,then code become very large.

Here my sample code:

```
var TextBox = React.createClass({
  setTextState : function(event){ 
    idval = event.target.id;
    console.log(idval);
    this.setState({idval  : event.target.value}); //Here the issue
  },

  content: function() {

    name1 = "task_1";
    name2 = "task_2";
    name3 = "task_3";
    name4 = "task_4";
    name5 = "task_5";
    name6 = "task_6";
    name7 = "task_7";

    return [
      <td> <TextInput type="text" /></td>, <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name1} id={name1} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>,
      <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name2} id={name2} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>, <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name3} id={name3} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>,
      <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name4} id={name4} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>, <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name5} id={name5} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>,
      <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name6} id={name6} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>, <td> <TextInput type="text" name={name7} id={name7} setText={this.setTextState}/></td>
    ]
  },

  submitValue : function() {

  },

  render: function() {
    return (<tr>{this.content()}<td><input type="button" onClick={this.submitValue}/></td></tr>);
  }
});
```

Comment: "All other input values are over write" -- I think you need to clarify what's happening, because this isn't clear to me.

Comment: Here Input Text field name is task_1,task_2 etc.  When i enter values in textfield and trying to fetch all these values i get only last inserted values .

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to set a state variable named `idval`, this is not correct:

```
this.setState({idval  : event.target.value}); //Here the issue
```

That is to say, JavaScript does not use the value of the variable `idval` as the key for the object; it uses the string literal `"idval"`. See this code for an example:

```js
var val = "testing";
var a = { val: 1 };
document.write("a.testing: " + a[val]);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("a.val: " + a["val"]);
```

It seems more likely, based on your setup, that you're trying to set a state variable named `task_1`, `task_2`, etc. To do so, you'd want something more like this:

```
setTextState : function(event){ 
  idval = event.target.id;
  console.log(idval);
  var stateUpdate = {};
  stateUpdate[idval] = event.target.value;
  this.setState(stateUpdate);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "idval" variable has the correct value, then the setState() call should work as you expect. You can try to copy the currentState and append to it and see if it works. If it doesn't work, please post the full code.

```
setTextState : function(event){ 
    idval = event.target.id;
    console.log(idval);
    newState = this.state;
    newState.idval = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState); 
},
```

Comment: Generating error . Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible solution. BTW, what react version are you using?